# Vectorizing Two Sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

Tags: statistics, matlab, vectorization

I'm implementing the [Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) in MATLAB. I must admit I know very little of formal statistics and was simply trying to implement the description in wikipedia's page.

Right now I take as input the two vectors to be compared `x1` and `x2`, and optionally the p-value that the check will run on. It outputs `1` if the vectors pass the test and `0` if they do not.

A couple of questions I have:

> Is there a better way to compute the empirical distribution functions?

Right now I evaluate the empirical distribution function at the points defined in the vector `t`. In my naive approximation, I made it go from the smallest value of the vectors to the largest, using twice as many points as the vector with the most points. I have no idea is this is the best way to compute it, and suspect the vector doesn't have to be nearly as dense.

> Can I vectorize the search through the `t` vector?

Right now I have a for loop that goes through every value of `t`and computes the empirical distribution function in that way. It seems that there might be a way to vectorize this operation further and get rid of the for loop. Haven't figured out a good way to do it however.

And of course, any other suggestions are welcome!

My code is below:

```
function [OUT] = k_stest(x1,x2,p)

% Set default p-value
    if nargin == 2 
        p = 0.05;
    end 

% Compute lenghts
    N1 = length(x1); 
    N2 = length(x2);

% Set vector t over which the empirical distribution function will be computed.
    t = linspace(min(min([x1 x2])),max(max([x1 x2])),2*max([N1 N2]));

% Initialize the statistic, negative values guarantees it will be overwritten by first call.
    D = -1; 

% Set c from tabulated values
    if p == 0.10
        c = 1.22;
    elseif p == 0.05
        c = 1.36;
    elseif p == 0.025
        c = 1.48;
    elseif p == 0.01
        c = 1.63;
    elseif p == 0.005
        c = 1.73;
    elseif p == 0.001
        c = 1.95;
    else
        disp('Invalid p-value. Only p = 0.10 0.05 0.025 0.01 0.005 0.001 are supported')
        return
    end

% Search though the vector t, computing the empirical distribution function for each t, 
% and overwriting the statistic if a higher value is found.
    for i = 1:length(t)
        F1 = sum(x1<=t(i))/N1;
        F2 = sum(x2<=t(i))/N2;
        if abs(F2-F1) > D
            D = abs(F2-F1);
        end
    end

% Compare the statistic to determine if the samples pass or fail.
    if D == -1;
       disp('Error, invalid input vectors')
       return
    elseif D > c*sqrt((N1+N2)/(N1*N2));
        OUT = 0;
    else
        OUT = 1;
    end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll take this in chronological order, from the top down. I think I have covered all aspects of the code =)

```
function [OUT] = k_stest(x1,x2,p)
```

This looks nice, but it would be better if you had spaces between the input arguments. Also, `k_stest` is not a very good name, as it's hard to understand what it does just be looking at the name. I read in another review that "You don't need the brackets around the output variable, but you should always include it". I don't necessarily agree,  I usually omit them, but that's just a matter of personal preferences.

---

```
% Set default p-value
    if nargin == 2 
        p = 0.05;
    end
```

This is OK. Depending on how you call the function you might add some additional checks. Is `p` a scalar? Are `x1` and `x2` vectors? This is not necessary, but can be useful if you want to use this function a long time from now and don't remember the specifics. [`assert`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/assert.html) can be very useful here.

---

```
% Compute lenghts
    N1 = length(x1); 
    N2 = length(x2);
```

`numel` (number of elements) is better than `length`. It's more robust and a lot faster for long vectors.

---

```
% Set vector t over which the empirical distribution function will be computed.
    t = linspace(min(min([x1 x2])),max(max([x1 x2])),2*max([N1 N2]));
```

This is dangerous, and a bit messy.

`[x1 x2]` assumes both `x1` and `x2` are row-vectors, i.e. horizontal vectors. A lot of functions in Matlab returns vectors as column-vectors i.e. vertical vectors by default, including the [`colon`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) operator (:).

If you happen to call this function with two vertical vectors instead of two horizontal vectors, this would fail (due to `[x1 x2]`).

Instead, you should do:

```
x12 = [x1(:); x2(:)]; 
t = linspace(min(x12), max(x12), 2*max([N1, N2]));
```

This way you're converting `x1` and `x2` to vertical vectors, and concatenate them vertically, prior to the `linspace` call. Now you only need one call to `max` and `min`.

---

The way you're initializing `D` is OK!

---

```
% Set c from tabulated values
    if p == 0.10
        c = 1.22;
    elseif p == 0.05
        c = 1.36;
    ...
```

Comparing floating point values using `==` is dangerous. For instance `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3` will return `false`. Instead, you should compare the values with the desired value, but with some tolerance (for instance `eps`).

```
    if abs(p - 0.10) < eps
        c = 1.22; 
    elseif abs(p-0.05) < eps
        c = 1.36;
```

If two values are closer to each other than `+/- eps` then they are essentially equal.

---

```
% Search though the vector t, computing the empirical distribution function for each t, 
% and overwriting the statistic if a higher value is found.
    for i = 1:length(t)
        F1 = sum(x1<=t(i))/N1;
        F2 = sum(x2<=t(i))/N2;
        if abs(F2-F1) > D
            D = abs(F2-F1);
        end
    end
```

You are right, vectorization is the way to go! Use `bsxfun` to create a logical matrix where each element that satisfy the condition `x1 <= t(ii)` are true and the others are false. Then sum the entire mask, and take the maximum difference.

```
mask1 = bsxfun(@le, x1(:), t);
mask2 = bsxfun(@le, x2(:), t);
s1 = sum(mask1) / N1;
s2 = sum(mask2) / N2;
D = max(abs(s1 - s2));
```

---

```
% Compare the statistic to determine if the samples pass or fail.
    if D == -1;
       disp('Error, invalid input vectors')
       return
    elseif D > c*sqrt((N1+N2)/(N1*N2));
        OUT = 0;
    else
        OUT = 1;
    end    
end
```

The check for invalid input vectors should be in the start of the function. I can't see a reason why you want it in the end instead. And as far as I can tell it will never fail (if the input is invalid then you will get an error further up).

Instead of the `if` and `elseif`, you can simply do:

```
OUT = D <= c*sqrt((N1+N2)/(N1*N2));
```

---

To sum it all up, your function can be written like this. I've omitted the comment for simplicity. You should include them in your code.

```
function OUT = k_stest(x1, x2, p)

if nargin == 2
    p = 0.05;
end

% Add check for invalid input vectors!

N1 = numel(x1);
N2 = numel(x2);

x12 = [x1(:); x2(:)]; 
t = linspace(min(x12), max(x12), 2*max([N1, N2]));

if abs(p - 0.10) < eps
    c = 1.22; 
elseif abs(p-0.05) < eps
    c = 1.36;
% Continue with the rest of the values
%
end

mask1 = bsxfun(@le, x1(:), t);
mask2 = bsxfun(@le, x2(:), t);
s1 = sum(mask1) / N1;
s2 = sum(mask2) / N2;
D = max(abs(s1 - s2));

OUT = D <= c*sqrt((N1+N2)/(N1*N2));

end
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I didn't know about bsxfun, that will be extremely useful in the future!

Comment: Yes, `bsxfun` is one of the most powerful tools in Matlab. Combine it with `reshape` and `permute` and your functions will be fast as h... =)